# UIView background pattern

Tags: iphone, uiview, background

Can I achieve the same as a following:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]];
```

using IB only? Without need to write such a codeline?
It seems that IB only allows to set up plain color, not images as background.

Comment: IB is very limited when you need to customize UI. I try not to use IB so that i can create more beautiful and specific layouts and interactions to the user.

Comment: @Edmar Bad advice. Do as much as you can in IB.  It can't get you all the way, but it can help you get a lot of cruft out of the way so that you can focus on the more beautiful and specific layouts/interacts for the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interface Builder doesn't allow the use of a background pattern. However you could simply overlay the background with the appropriate image within an UIImageView. This would give the desired look to the application, without having to use the code you posted above.

However, I strongly disagree that you should use only Interface Builder. Code is a lot cleaner in my eyes and allows for a lot more control over what you build.

Comment: Pattern would be the preferred approach, especially if it really is a pattern.  The frame buffer will only have to cache the one tile for repeating, so you'll consume less memory.  Plus, with the UIImageView, you have the additional overhead of a view object.

Comment: Agreed. Like I said, I disagree that he should use and only use IB. I think it is a lot smoother implementation with the use of doing it through code.

Comment: @theOrkus Not necessarily.  Keeping as much in IB creates a cleaner implementation of MVC.  Your view is separate and distinct from the controller.  This is especially so when using IB to position your elements.  Why should your controller care about those kinds of details?  Do as much of that in IB so your controller can focus on business logic.

Comment: Sure, that is true. But when it comes to specifically handling a patterned image as the view's background, then it is definitely needed as code. I have nothing against IB, but for what he needs to accomplish, it is apparent code is needed instead.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done in IB, but got the code right.  Despite what others have commented, use IB to the fullest extent possible, that way you can focus your efforts on the real business logic of your application, only customizing further where IB doesn't reach.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you can't do this solely in IB/storyboard. But with @IBDesignable you *can* add a few lines to your subclass and have it *show up* in IB, which is pretty cool.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class MyView: UIView {
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.addPattern()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    self.addPattern()
}

private func addPattern() {
    let image = UIImage(named: "MyPattern", in: Bundle(for: self.dynamicType), compatibleWith: nil)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image!)
}

}
```

Then just change your storyboard/IB view's class to MyView.